# How to use the "hidden" attribute?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I can see that official polymer elements are using `hidden` attribute like so:

`hidden$="[[!someValue]]"` and `hidden$=[[someValue]]`

However, in my case, `someValue` is a huge object and while above expressions still work, for `hidden$=[[someValue]]` I can see something like this:

[image: serialized object as the value of the hidden attribute]

App does unnecessary work serializing that object + having all that text makes it harder for me to work with DevTools.

So, I used `hidden=[[someValue]]` and `hidden=[[!someValue]]` instead. These work like a charm.

My questions are:

- Can I safely use `hidden=` instead of `hidden$=`?
- Why this even works? I understood that `$=` sets attributes and `=` sets properties.
- If I should use `hidden$=` whats the best way to do `hidden$=[[bigObject]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can safely use the `hidden` attribute or property. [This polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/blob/938051272519053867b5bafa7411e7afefdd2c01/src/ShadowDOM/wrappers/HTMLElement.js#L259) from the webcomponentsjs library says that setting the property will also reflect to the attribute.  That would explain why `$=` and `=` have the same behavior.

Since that setter overrides the value to `''`, I would expect that setting the property (`=`) would use less memory and be more performant, but obviously benchmarks are the only real way to know for sure.